# Dragons and gems

Tags: visual

Separate dragons from gems in each grid using as few straight lines as possible.  Each line should go all the way through the grid.

[image]

The answer to the puzzle is one word.

Comment: For the accepted answer to work, it should be specified that the lines must be some of the lines that make the grid.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yes, this is implied

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the solution is:

> [image]

Small explanation:

> If there is a dragon adjacent to a gem, then there must be a line between them. For some puzzles like #1, #2, and #4, three lines are the minimum one as we cannot construct a solution with only two lines.

And the secret word is:

> **JASPER**, <s>anagram of the letters formed by the lines</s> taken from the letters formed by the lines, reading from red to purple gems in rainbow order (thanks @Deusovi!).

Comment: (It's not just an anagram - the gems are all different colors, so you can get the secret word by reading in rainbow order!)

Comment: @Deusovi ah how did I miss that.. >< thanks!